# Convert code behind to XAML code - DatePicker

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datepicker

I'm working on converting some of my behind-code to XAML code. I'm not 100% sure how to access the parts of the DatePicker object with XAML like I did with my behind-code. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Behind-code:
I was just passing the name of the DatePicker field and Page that it was located on.

```
private void DatePickerUpdater(DatePicker DPobj, Page PGobj)
    {
        Grid grid = (Grid)DPobj.Template.FindName("PART_Root", DPobj);
        ColumnDefinitionCollection Column = grid.ColumnDefinitions;
        Column.Clear();
        ColumnDefinition c1 = new ColumnDefinition();
        c1.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
        ColumnDefinition c2 = new ColumnDefinition();
        c2.Width = new GridLength(50,GridUnitType.Pixel);
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c1);
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c2);



        Button button = (Button)DPobj.Template.FindName("PART_Button", DPobj);
        button.Template = (ControlTemplate)PGobj.FindResource("myTemplate");
        button.Width = 50;
    }
```

XAML

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="myTemplate" TargetType="Button">
        <Image Name="calendar" Source="/Image/calendar.png" Height="30" Width="30"/>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: you can add the template from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468215%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and edit the template of the PART_Button. Add the template as part of your xaml

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I think I'm starting to understand how to create the Style change. Now how would I make it reusable? I see how I can write it directly into the DatePicker object.